# Get Values in .Net Core Api send via PostAsJsonAsync in .Net Core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I get the values in Backend? Key is `null` and login is `false`. `[FromQuery]`, `[FromBody]` or `[FromForm]` did not work

net core Application (Frontend)

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("stamptimes", new { key, login });
```

net core Api (Backend)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostNewStamptime(string key, bool login)
    {...}
```

Comment: you send an object and your backend excepts deconstructed values. your API should look like `PostNewStamptime([FromBody] LoginModel model)`. And `LoginModel` should contain key and login properties.

Comment: A model for one method sounds like a workaround. is it my best option?

Comment: AFAIK, model for Post methods is the commonly-held approach. Maybe You can alter endpoints statusVerb to Get and send the parameters in query strings. That's when you can reach them via `[FromQuery]`. But this is semantically wrong.

Comment: Thank you! Post your comment as Answer and i mark it as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you send an object and your backend excepts deconstructed values. your API should look like below;

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostNewStamptime([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {...}
```

And LoginModel should contain key and login properties like Below

```cs
public class LoginModel {
    public string Key {get;set;}
    public bool Login {get;set;}
}
```

Also, you can avoid using a model by altering endpoints statusVerb to Get and send the parameters in query strings. That's when you can reach them via [FromQuery]. **But this is semantically wrong.**